# Music application that reads existing ratings from ID3 tags

Tags: music, banshee, id3

Banshee for some odd reason is not reading my existing ID3 tags from my windows music library. This is really odd because I have been using banshee for many years now based on the purpose of being able to read my tags. I noticed that in this new version the options menu has changed.

Does anyone know of an alternative app that can read rating tags natively on Ubuntu?

I am down to try anything I just hope for the love of god my tags haven't been erased. I have over 12k pieces of music :(

Thanks.

Comment: Did you already try Rhythmbox?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options that should read your ID3 tags such as Rythmbox, Clementine, Amarok or if you really wanted you could even run iTunes through wine. However, I am surprised Banshee doesn't have this feature.